# How to Pass Hidden field value in HyperLink control in navigateURL attibute?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can any one tell me how to pass any hidden filed value in Query string with hyperlink control.please see the problem in below code:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkComment" runat="server" 
    onclick="return GB_show('Comment', this.href, 500, 650)" 
    ImageUrl="~/Images/Resources/forum.png" ToolTip="Comment" Text="Comment" 
    NavigateUrl="~/Recruiter/ViewForumComment.aspx?Id=<% hdnReqId.Value %>&Type=R">
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Can you describe little bit more what exactly you want?

Answer (score 0):

Query string is visible to the user. You can use [URL ReWriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877702/how-to-pass-hidden-field-value-in-hyperlink-control-in-navigateurl-attibute)

Or

Simply pass them as Session Objects

Answer (score 0):

Jquery will do things for. Do redirect code in your js method like:

```
 function GB_show(Comment, url, t1, t2) {
            ////YourCode
            location.href = url + "&q=" + $("#hdnValue").val();
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkComment" runat="server" onclick="return GB_show('Comment', this.href, 500, 650);" ImageUrl="~/Images/1.jpg" ToolTip="Comment" Text="Comment" ></asp:HyperLink>
```

on page load write:

```
url = string.Format("~/Recruiter/ViewForumComment.aspx?Id={0}&Type=R", hdnReqId.Value);
hlnkComment.NavigateUrl = url;
```

Comment: Thanks Dude..i think its usefull